# What is the best time to leave from Baja Mexico to San Diego, California through Vehicle/Pedestrian crossings?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, borders, mexico, california

What is the absolute best time to leave from Baja Mexico to re-enter San Diego, California by either vehicle or pedestrian?

This is assuming you don't have a Sentri Pass.

I went to Mexico a few weeks ago and had a terrible time entering the border from Mexico into San Diego. Took me 4 hours by vehicle through San Ysidro Border at 10AM on a Regular Sunday.

From my understanding there is about 7 Border crossings of Mexico.
[Wiki Border crossing of Mexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mexico%E2%80%93United_States_border_crossings)

Is there a list out there that shows the best times to re-enter San Diego Area through vehicle or pedestrian?

Comment: Current wait times are available at https://bwt.cbp.gov/

Comment: Thats nice to view real time border crossings, but i was wondering if there was a "Best TIME" to go. From my understanding. 1AM-4AM on any  border/given day isn't that bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site has eight border crossings listed: http://traffic.calit2.net/border/border-wait-times.php?type=passenger&sub=standard&port=250401#

They graph wait times there so you can see the average delay for a given day of the week. It looks like the slow & busy times vary depending on what day of the week it is, so you'll need to check and take a look at the graph for whatever day you're planning on crossing on.